# Binding Between Two Isolated Scopes

Tags: angularjs

I have two directives with isolated scopes. Is it possible to pass information between the two using binding?

With or without transclusion, parentSq in data view B is always undefined.

Thanks

HTML:

```
<dataview-a parent-sq="rootStudioQuery">
  <dataview-b parent-sq="dataViewAStudioQuery">
  </dataview-b>
</dataview-a>
```

Directives:

```
app.directive('dataviewA', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
      parentSq:"="
    },
    controller:function($scope){
      debugger;
      $scope.dataViewAStudioQuery = {
        filters:[]
      };
    }
}
});

app.directive('dataviewB', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
      parentSq:"="
    },
    transclude:true, 
    link:function(scope,e,a){
    //scope.parentSq  is always undefined
    }
}
});
```

Comment: "Between Two Isolated Scopes" what is their relation? Sibling? Parent-Child?

Comment: Sorry, didn't include the HTML. Parent/Child relationship.

Comment: in that case make the child directive use `require: "^^dataviewA"` to have the `dataviewA` controller passed to it in the 4th argument to the link function.

Comment: Tried this. scope.parentSq is still undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

Basically, you are missing an output object from the parent directive. I have added outputObject: "=" to the scope of the parent directive:

```
scope:{
  parentSq:"=",
  outputObject: "="
}
```

And modified the child directive to watch parentSq:

```
      scope.$watch('parentSq', function(oldVal,newVal){

        console.log(scope.parentSq);

      });
```

And modified the HTML like so (to pass output object):

```
<dataview-a parent-sq="rootStudioQuery" output-object='dataViewAStudioQuery'>
  <dataview-b parent-sq="dataViewAStudioQuery">
  </dataview-b>
</dataview-a>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/jxzw18kZwkk3YSgV2f3A?p=preview

```
app.directive('dataviewA', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
      parentSq:"=",
      outputObject: "="
    },
    controller:function($scope){
      $scope.outputObject = {
        filters:[]
      };
    }
}
});

app.directive('dataviewB', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
      parentSq:"="
    },
    transclude:true, 
    link:function(scope,e,a){

      scope.$watch('parentSq', function(oldVal,newVal){

        console.log(scope.parentSq);

      });


    //scope.parentSq  is always undefined
    }
}
```

-- Old Answer using broadcasts / $rootScope --

How about $rootScope.$broadcast, or $rootScope.$emit? Use $emit if you do not need to broadcast below the $rootScope to child scopes.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('something', {
  //data object here
  example: 'Example Data'
});

$rootScope.$emit('something', {
  //data object here
  example: 'Example Data'
});
```

Listen with

```
$rootScope.$on('something', function (event, data) {
    // data has example: 'Example Data' within
});
```

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: I need to do this without accessing rootScope or broadcasting events. Why wouldn't two way binding work?

Comment: I checked out your plunkr. scope.parentSq is still undefined in the link function. I need to get at the parentSq in child scopes to perform some operations on them, I wont be displaying them in HTML.

Comment: Alright, try the new plunker I added. With the watch function, you will find parentSq is defined.

Comment: Nice. THANKS.  I assumed the binding would be set by the time the child link function was called. Looks like when that function is called, it hasn't completed the digest cycle yet.